# How to add endorsed directory to runnable jar

Tags: java, endorsed

I am using endorsed directory for some jar which can be used from command line.
Now I want to make jar as runnable with endorsed directory so that user can just click the runnable jar file to run the application.

I am using Eclipse Helios and Java 6.

Can anyone tell me how to do the above mentioned task.

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: What jars are you using from endorsed directory ?

Comment: jaxb-api.jar and jaxws-api.jar

Answer (score 0):

From Eclipse

- Right Click the project and select "Export"
- Select Runnable JAR File
- Select output direct
- Press Next
- Press Next
- Press Finish

Once it is exported it ,let say in C:\

Run Command prompt and change it to c: and run

```
java -jar XXXX.jar
```

thats it.

***Packaging JAR as EXE.***

Download Launch4J [here](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

***Screenshots***

[Click here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/)

Comment: ,I know how to make runnable jar in Eclipse.

I am using endorsed directories with my jar. For using endorsed directories, I am using following command:

'java -cp . -jar -Djava.endorsed.dirs=./endorsed my.jar'

Instead of these path, I want to use runnable jar so that it will contain endorsed directories, I made runnable jar but it failed to run as it requires libraries which are in endorsed directories. 

My application worked when I gave aforementioned command line command.

Comment: Yes. It worked by using java -jar. But I want to use it as application without using any extra .bat file.

Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Yes. Its easy. See my updated answer. Upvote and accept it as answer if you think it helps.